# AWS ElasticBeanstalk Worker enviornment, how to redirect SQS POST request to another port other than 80

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-sqs, web-worker

I have a NestJS application running on an Elastic Beanstalk worker environment. The application is written in Javascript and not in Typescript. So it cannot be built using the `nest build` command. Hence I'm just running it using the package.json start script, `node index.js`. And the application is running fine.

Now it's running on PORT 3002. But the SQS is POST ing messages from the queue to `http://localhost:80/`, the default PORT.

The question is how I would customize the SQS to POST it on port 3002 instead of the default 80.

I tried setting up the .ebextensions config file in the following way:

```
.ebextensions/worker.config


option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    SQS_POST_PATH: /
    SQS_POST_PORT: 3002
```

but it did not help.

Is there any way it can be customized?